# How harmless bacteria on skin defence against harmful bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology, skin, immune-system

I have read that there are some harmless bacteria live on skin and they also have role in protecting body against some harmful bacteria but how do they do so? I mean how these bacteria are able to resist other bacteria which are harmful?

Comment: Another way to look at this is, you have a limited amount of skin. "Good" bacteria competes for space on the skin with "bad" bacteria. They kind of strike a balance where harmless bacteria are more common. That protects you in that say you have a microabrasion on your skin; it's less likely to be invaded by harmful bacteria than not as-pathogenic bacteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations between organisms in complex ecosystems are various, so I won't give an exhaustive answer, only keys to understanding.

First, you need to consider that a bacterium harmful to humans is not necessary harmul to other bacteria. So there is no reason why our skin microbiota will only target/resist to human pathogens.

What's more, microbes are not inherently harmful to us. Their dangerosity also depends on the capacity of the skin to block them [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2746716/).

Then, microbial defence mechanisms depend on the kind of relation they have to the potential pathogen: competition, parasitism, predation, *etc*.

The [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2746716/) cited below will give you a nice overview on the topic.

---

[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2746716/) Cogen, A. L.; Nizet, V.; Gallo, R. L. (2008) Skin microbiota: a source of disease or defence? *British journal of dermatology*, **158**, 3, 442-455; doi: 10.1111/j.1365-2133.2008.08437.x